# transposing data by parts

Tags: awk, transpose

**I would like to transpose this data**:

```
ZA 1 snp10000-652219   A_A
ZA 1 snp10001-703514   A_T
ZA 1 snp10002-766996   A_A
ZA 1 snp10003-808120   A_T
ZA 10 snp10000-652219   A_A
ZA 10 snp10001-703514   A_A
ZA 10 snp10002-766996   A_A
ZA 10 snp10003-808120   A_A
```

**the desired output:**

```
ZA 1    A_A  A_T A_A A_T
ZA 10   A_A  A_A A_A A_A
```

The code i have tried :

```
      awk '
   { 
      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
       }
     }
     NF>p { p = NF }
    END {    
           for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
           str=a[1,j]
            for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
          str=str" "a[i,j];
              }
            print str
                 }
         }'
```

the problem is that it transposes the whole data

Comment: it's probably better described as: "concatenate last field based on first two fields"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{k=$1 FS $2; a[k]=a[k] FS $NF} 
   END {for(k in a) print k a[k]}' file | sort

ZA 1 A_A A_T A_A A_T
ZA 10 A_A A_A A_A A_A
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question originally was tagged 'perl' as well:

```
perl -ane '
    {
        if(defined($previous) and "@F[0,1]" ne $previous) {
            printf("% -7s %s\n",$previous,"@col_d");
            @col_d=()
        }
        push(@col_d,$F[-1]);
        $previous="@F[0,1]"
    }
    END {
        printf("% -7s %s\n",$previous,"@col_d")
    }
' file
```

Produces:

```
ZA 1    A_A A_T A_A A_T
ZA 10   A_A A_A A_A A_A
```